# Add custom text to ggplot when x axis is categorical

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I was trying to add custom text to my `ggplot` where `x-axis` is categorical. Below is my code

```
library(ggplot2)
data = rbind(data.frame('val' = c(10, 30, 15), 'name' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), group = 'gr1'), data.frame('val' = c(30, 40, 12), 'name' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), group = 'gr2'), data.frame('val' = c(10, 30, 15), 'name' = c('A', 'B', 'C'), group = 'gr3'))

ggplot(data,                        
       aes(x = group,
           y = val,
           fill = name)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity",
             position = "stack", width = .1) +
    geom_text(data = data.frame('group' = c('gr1', 'gr2', 'gr3'), 'label' = c('X', 'Y', 'Z')), mapping = aes(x = group, y = 40, label = label))
```

Above implementation is failing with error

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'name' not found
```

Could you please help me to correct this error?

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you specified `fill=name` as a global aesthetic but the dataframe passed to `geom_text` does not contain a column called `name`. To fix that make `fill=name` a local aes of `geom_col` or add `inherit=FALSE` to `geom_text`:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data,                        
       aes(x = group,
           y = val)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = name), width = .1) +
  geom_text(data = data.frame('group' = c('gr1', 'gr2', 'gr3'), 'label' = c('X', 'Y', 'Z')), mapping = aes(x = group, y = 40, label = label))
```

[image]